# Mavericks Server fails to log in Network Users from laptop

Tags: server.app, error, login

There is no way to remotely login from my laptop to the server

This is the error I get:

```
authorizationhost[1206]: ERROR
```

It is possible to login to that user from the Mac mini server.

Comment: Was there no text around the above line in the log? 'ERROR' isn't the most explanatory error message

Comment: Yes there was 6/14/14 10:26:47.861 authorizationhost[1206]: ERROR | -[HomeDirMounter mountNetworkHomeWithURL:attributes:dirPath:username:] | PremountHomeDirectoryWithAuthentication( url=afp://server.type.com/Home%20Folder, homedir=/Network/Servers/server.type.com/Volumes/Promise RAID/Home Folder/david, name=david ) returned 64

Comment: Basically I tried everything, I even destroyed the open directory to create a new one and created a new user, changed the certificates, verified that my laptop was enrolled and all the important ports on my router are open, I don't know what to do...